# How to include MFC and Visual Studio CRT libraries into MSI installer?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3

I'm trying to learn how to write MSI installer. I'm using WiX, and I'm curious. My application comes with the dependencies to the followign MFC and CRT libraries:

```
mfc90u.dll
msvcr90.dll
```

How do you install those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some choices listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). I recommend using the appropriate [redistributables](http://search.microsoft.com/en-us/DownloadResults.aspx?q=Visual+C%2b%2b+Redistributable+Package) instead of installing individual DLLs.

With WiX 3.6 and later, you can create a [chainer](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/) that runs multiple installers. You can create a VS project for that with a WiX Bootstrapper template.

Comment: Thanks. I don't need the whole set of MFC libraries to install the redistributable package. What if I install those 2 files into the local folder with my application?

Comment: That would work with the application loading the DLLs as local private assemblies. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235342(v=vs.90).aspx). In WiX, make them each a File wrapped in separate Components.

Comment: Thanks. Just from curiosity. If say, I place `mfc90u.dll` into my local folder and there's also `mfc90u.dll` in the system folder. Which one will be loaded into my app at startup?

Comment: See [Assembly Searching Sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374224(v=vs.85).aspx). You might also want to follow the link int the comments to that doc page. They support my recommendation to install using standalone (but chainable) redistributable packages. Either way, your application manifest has to support your choice.

Comment: I see. I was trying to find the redistributable copies of those two files and I have a dilemma. MS documentation says to take those from the 'VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.MFC' folder for Visual Studio. But when I compare them to the ones that are currently installed in my `WinSxS folder`, those files are different. So where do I take them from for distribution?

Comment: For both legal and technical reasons, I wouldn't take anything from the cache. My guess is that Microsoft is not updating the redistributes that ship with VS and VS service packs as rapidly as they are updating their complete C runtime distributions and end-user updates. I avoid these issues and put my trust in allowing Microsoft to maintain their libraries that I depend on by supplying updates on end-user's systems. But, of course, that can cause my deployed applications to run with untested combinations of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Distibuting the vcredist dlls as private DLLs creates security risks for the user, and is discouraged, however if you distribute the version mentioned it must live in a subfolder of the app folder with a name specified in msdn docs.  It is far better to use the vcredist exe (even if your app does not need all of the vc redist files),or the related msm.  The location of the msm or private dlls is part of your VS installation and detailed in the VS redistribution license.  The vcredist exe is available from microsoft's site.  There are many different versions of the vs 2008 redist.  Open your binary in a text editor and search for manifest to read the embedded manifest which details which version of the vcredist you need to deploy.  Never take anything from the SXS folder. Regarding wix you can add the msm to your msi but there are issues with doing that.  The prefered method is create a Wix bundle using the vcredist exe.